# What is the best way to scan a float and a double with scanf?

Tags: c

Consider this example:

```
float a;
double b;

scanf("%f%f", &a, &b);   // A
scanf("%Lf%Lf", &a, &b); // B
scanf("%f%Lf", &a, &b);  // C
scanf("%f%lf", &a, &b);  // D
```

Comment: isn't there a tag `I am stuck in the middle of an exam` instead of `homework`?

Answer (score 14):

You can use

```
scanf("%f %lf", &a, &b);
```

### **scanf type specifiers:**

- **c**: Single character: *Reads the next character. If a width different from 1 is specified, the function reads width characters and stores them in the successive locations of the array passed as argument. No null character is appended at the end.*
- **d**: Decimal integer: *Number optionally preceded with a + or - sign.*
- **e,E,f,g,G**: Floating point: *Decimal number containing a decimal point, optionally preceded by a + or - sign and optionally folowed by the e or E character and a decimal number. Two examples of valid entries are -732.103 and 7.12e4*
- **o**: Octal integer.
- **s**: String of characters: *This will read subsequent characters until a whitespace is found (whitespace characters are considered to be blank, newline and tab).*
- **u**: Unsigned decimal integer.
- **x,X**: Hexadecimal integer.

### **Modifiers:**

- **h** : short int (for d, i and n), or unsigned short int (for o, u and x)
- **l** : long int (for d, i and n), or unsigned long int (for o, u and x), or double (for e, f and g)
- **L** : long double (for e, f and g)

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: @Asha: If you feel this is the right answer, you should accept it. (Do yourself a favor and read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). This place works so well because it has a few rules. However, this also means that, when you do not play to the rules, this place doesn't work for you.)

Comment: You skipped the "why" part of the question, which is a bit more important than "pick D". Doing people's homework for them is great fun, but somewhat counterproductive when they're our future co-workers.

Answer (score 3):

[Look up the format string specification for `scanf()`.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/)